# Toning jiggly loose muscle

Tags: muscle, lower-body-strength

My question has two parts:

I have very muscular thighs and legs coming from years of swimming and running since I was younger.

The thing is, both my thighs and legs are pretty jiggly when I don't flex them. If I flex/tighten them, they look nice and muscular.

(1) What really is going on here ? Is it muscle laced with fat, or just muscle yet to be toned ?

(2) Can I work to tightening them up? Is it even possibly or is it just part of my physique? How do I tighten or tone them?

(For last 3 months, I have been on a workout program for upper and lower body.My lower body workout consists of lunges, squats and other compound trainings)

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.  Could it be muscle and fat?  Sure.  Of course relaxed muscle isn't going to be as firm as tensed muscle.  The lower body work you have planned looks good.

Comment: This is for sure extra body fat that you need to burn off! I have the same problem! You just need to do running exercises or cardio excercises in general to lose this extra body fat that are covering your muscles!

Comment: Unless you're squatting 2x your body weight (ie: 180lb human pushing 360lb on your back) I wouldn't chaulk up your leg size to "very muscular". Look at an Olympic speed skater: their legs are jiggling around when they run.

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to answer your question without seeing you, or having your body composition values. However, a muscle cannot be toned, it can either grow or shrink (hypertrophy and atrophy).

Also, since there is *gravity*, you cannot expect a muscle to be tight all the time :)